# gvim auto copy selected text to system clipboard (to share it with apps )

Tags: vim, clipboard

I wonder, how i can enable auto copy of selected text into '+'
register in Ubuntu (to share clipboard between apps)?
On win XP, i have

> set guioptions+=a

and its works perfectly, but not in Ubuntu 11.10.

Also, i tried

> set clipboard=unnamedplus,unnamed,autoselect,exclude:cons\|linux.

but without success.

Please do not offer hand-click solutions like
`vmap <C-Insert> "+y` and mouse copy/paste.

test case (with "behave mswin" option):

1. open gvim
2. <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, move cursor and <kbd>Esc</kbd> (select lines in visual mode)
3. go to firefox and click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Insert</kbd> to paste text

**Solution**

In this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/1b50de7f4163dbb5/b36e113b3abebad9?lnk=gst&q=vakulenko&pli=1), problem was solved.

You need to apply patch from Christian Brabandt.

Also, if you have problem with paste with <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>insert</kbd> after recompilation in ubuntu, you can add this in your vimrc:

```
if has("gui_running")
    map <silent> <S-Insert> "+p
    cmap <S-Insert> <C-R>+
    imap <silent> <S-Insert> <Esc>"+pa
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `"+y` work? It's not a suggestion: if this command doesn't work, you may have some underlying problems that prevent a simple solution. So it needs to be checked first, even if it sounds stupid.

`set clipboard+=unnamedplus` is enough **if your version of Vim supports it**. Mine is 7.3.35 and it doesn't work (Vim doesn't complain, though).

I don't know exactly which patch introduced `unnamedplus` but you can do `:help 'clipboard'` (with the single quotes) to have a list of available options. If `unnamedplus` is listed, the snippet above should fix your problem. If it's not there you won't be able to use it (obviously): time to re-assess your "do not offer hand-click solutions like `vmap "+y` and mouse copy/paste" requirement or compile a more recent version of Vim.

Comment: In Linux exist two global clipboards, + and * . Your answer not handle * clipboard. I advice you to read thread in Solution section, to understand more the problem.

Comment: The OP had some missing text due to missing code formatting; that snippet should read `vmap <C-insert> "+y`

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
set guioptions+=P
```

Explanation:

TLDR: `a` puts text into `"*` register. `P` puts text into `"+` register

From `:help guioptions`

> 'a'    Autoselect:  If present, then whenever VISUAL mode is started,
>   or the Visual area extended, Vim tries to become the owner of      the
>   windowing system's global selection.  This means that the         Visually
>   highlighted text is available for pasting into other      applications as
>   well as into Vim itself.  When the Visual mode        ends, possibly due to
>   an operation on the text, or when an      application wants to paste the
>   selection, the highlighted text       is automatically yanked into the "*
>   selection register.       Thus the selection is still available for
>   pasting into other        applications after the VISUAL mode has ended.
>             If not present, then Vim won't become the owner of the      windowing system's global selection unless explicitly told to       by a
>   yank or delete operation for the "* register.         The same applies to
>   the modeless selection.
>
> 'P'   Like autoselect but using the "+ register instead of the "*
>   register.